# Need to Restrict shipping in Magento 1.9 to only 48 contiguous state

Tags: shipping, ce-1.9.0.1, shipping-address

We've set up the site to only being able to purchase within the United States, but many of the US Territories are showing up in the checkout like Guam, Puerto Rico, etc. Is there any way to remove them?

All I can find are steps on how to deal with them in regards to Free Shipping, but that's not what I need.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove them from your DB.
Check `directory_country_region` table and remove the region you do not want to show up.

If you do not have phpMyAdmin access here is an SQL example:

```
delete from directory_country_region where default_name='Guam';
```

Comment: This solution has crossed my mind before, but I first wanted to see if there was a way to do it programmatically or if there was an extension that could hide certain states/territories without having to delete default magento data in the database.

Comment: Two ways you could do this actually do this the right way.
Build out the actual code to do this. (unfortnuately i don't have this code for you)
There are extensions out there just for this.
https://marketplace.magento.com/eltrino-eltrino-region.html